# How to display maps in android mapview

Tags: java, android, json

[image]

I create the google map in android mapview.but display greyscale in mapview.iam using own API key for google mapview.

How to get map in mapview without greyscale?

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyBNpjyktHItZYm4no0wTvzSv8tWU5gaoy0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Code,its display greyscale. How to resolve this?

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-using-onmylocationchangelistener-in-google-map-android-api-v2/ i refer this link but display blank output[image]

Comment: Note that you are trying to use Maps V1, which is deprecated. Please consider using Maps V2. Beyond that, you might consider posting a screenshot showing the effect that you are seeing.

Comment: Divya you might be getting tiles on the display because when I use this code I get the same result, I tried 2 days.

Comment: did you get any ideas?

Comment: put your screenshot of output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as CommonsWare said, you should be using the v2 maps API. When did you request the key? You can't request Maps v1 keys after March 2013. I suspect you may be trying to use a v2 key with the v1 API. Check your logcat to see if there's a message.

See [Google Maps API (v2)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Another possibility is that you registered the key incorrectly. Are you sure you have the SHA1 fingerprint of the right key? If you registered a v1 key when they were available, are you sure you're signing with the same key you registered?

Also - it looks like, based on your status bar, that you're not getting a good connection. Google maps requires a network connection. Try turning on wifi to check if it works. If so, it's likely that you just weren't getting the maps downloaded. If wifi works, try allowing the app to sit for a bit with wifi turned off and see if the maps eventually load over 3G.

Answer (score 1):

```
    check below example it working...

[example link1][1]

[example link2][2]

[example link3][3]

    - manifest : Provide all need Permision in This Example i applied Find And Navigation 



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demomap1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demomap1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapv2demo1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapv2demo1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapv2demo1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value=" Put Key Here" />
    </application>

</manifest>

     - Layout xml---I use the com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment to show map

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_find"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/et_location"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="find" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Enter Location"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_find" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>


     - Code to integration Map v2 in code the Intent is call the map app which install in phone.. 

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
        GoogleMap mapView;
        LatLng latLong;
        MarkerOptions markerOption;
        Button btnFind;
        EditText etLocation;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.mapview)).getMap();

            btnFind=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_find);
            etLocation=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_location);
            btnFind.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String destination=etLocation.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="
                            + destination));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
  [1]: http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/02/google-maps-android-api-v2.html
  [2]: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html
  [3]: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/
```

Comment: i also tried 3rd link but it display blank view.how to resolve this?

Comment: @Divya first check you Must on Map v2 Api From Google Console Api and Second Your Check Your Key and Try 1st link and i put the code which I tested it work ... Note :- Put API_KEY in Menifest          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value=" Put Key Here" />

Comment: yes its worked but i need to display map in  mapview fragment

Comment: i get api key using Google Console and put into myapplication but its loads blank

Comment: @Divya On the service of Map If not Go in Service and on and for MapView Fragment I am Not try it ..1st tell you got a map or not you say it work so what you want..

Comment: i am already put my output screen given above .i didnot get map.your code is works well.in my code i am also using fragment.fragment cannot load the google map.how to load the map in fragment

Comment: @Divya I am not sure but your read it..FragmentActivity is provided by the Android Support Library v4 to allow Android platforms before Honeycomb to use fragments. With Honeycomb and later, fragments are supported using by the standard Activity class

The catch is, depending on the activity class you choose, you cannot use the same fragment class:

Comment: with android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, you muse use android.support.v4.app.Fragment
with android.app.Activity, you must use android.app.FragmentNote the package difference

Now, with respect to Google Maps v2 for Android, you have two Fragment implementation :

MapFragment which extends android.app.Fragment for Honeycomb and later

Comment: Note the package difference

Now, with respect to Google Maps v2 for Android, you have two Fragment implementation :

MapFragment which extends android.app.Fragment for Honeycomb and later
SupportMapFragment which extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment for support of the older android versions